# Asymptote: Label a point on surface

Tags: asymptote

I have the code for planes intersecting a hyperboloid from a previous thread (see below) and I now want to label the upper point where the hyperboloid intersects the vertical axis as A.

If I try to do this with a simple dot command, the dot appears to be half-hidden behind the hyperboloid which is undesirable. Now from reading p77-78 of this guide (http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/asymptote_tutorial.pdf), it appears to be because Asymptote doesn't know which is meant to be on top and is just guessing. The suggested resolution is to cut out the relevant part of the surface but they only provide an example of how to do this for something simple like a circle but my situation with the hyperboloid is much more complicated. Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks.

```
settings.outformat="pdf";
settings.render = 16;
settings.prc = false;
import three;
import graph;

size(8cm,0);

currentprojection = orthographic(2,0,10, up=Y);

draw(-2X--2X,arrow=Arrow3(),L=Label("$X$", position=EndPoint));
draw(-2Y--2Y,arrow=Arrow3(),L=Label("$U$", position=EndPoint));
draw(-2Z--2Z);
label("$w \to \infty$",(2,1,0));

draw((0.5,-1,1)--(0.7,-0.2,1),arrow=Arrow3(size=5bp),L=Label("$\Pi_w$", position=BeginPoint));
draw((1.5,-1.3,0)--(1.3,-0.8,0),arrow=Arrow3(size=5bp),L=Label("$X+U = L \mathrm{e}^{w/L}$", position=BeginPoint));

pen color = red;
material surfacepen = material(diffusepen=color+opacity(1.0), emissivepen=0.5*color);
pen color = blue;
material planepen = material(diffusepen=opacity(0.4), emissivepen=0.8*color);

real f(real x) { return .5*x*x+.5; }
path3 p3 = path3(graph(f, -1, 1, operator..));

surface solidsurface = surface(p3, c=O, axis=X);
draw(solidsurface, surfacepen=surfacepen);

path3 p = (-1,1,1) -- (1,-1,1)  -- (1,-1,-1)  -- (-1,1,-1) -- cycle;
for (real s=0.0; s<=1.0; s+=0.5)
{
    draw(shift(s*X)*p);
    draw(surface(shift(s*X)*p), surfacepen=planepen);
}

shipout(scale(4.0)*currentpicture.fit());
```

[image]

Comment: Try using layering as described in Section 3.15 ("Layering: moving objects closer to camera") of the document you cite.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Hi. I don't understand how I should use the code at the bottom of p87. Should I first declare e.g. "P=(1,2,3);" and then copy and past that code and then "draw P;"? This gives me syntax errors though.

Comment: @CharlesStaats Also, wouldn't this be dealt with in Section 3.17 (Writing on Surfaces) which is incomplete?

Comment: Section 3.17 is intended to be about [things like this](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/gallery/Klein.pdf), which I'm guessing is not what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The problem you are having is that part of your dot ( = tiny sphere) is actually positioned behind the hyperbola. The solution is to move the dot directly toward the camera. So, after including the function definitions from section 3.15, write your `dot` command as before, but replace, e.g., `(1,2,3)` with `towardcamera((1,2,3))`.

Comment: @CharlesStaats I have exactly copied the definitions from Section 3.15 and then I included "dot(towardcamera(1,2,3))" but when running the code I receive the error "cannot call 'triple towardcamera(triple pt, real distance=<default>, projection P=<default>)' with parameters '(int,real,int)'" and everything following this line in the code fails to compile. It seems to be complaining about the definitions rather than my code for the dot?

Comment: You are missing the extra pair of parentheses: `towardcamera((1,2,3))`, not `towardcamera(1,2,3)`. This is necessary because `towardcamera` takes one `triple`, not three `real`s.

Comment: @CharlesStaats ah i see. thanks. Final point, how can I move a label attached to this dot? Using the standard "dot(towardcamera((0,0.5,0)),L=Label("$A$");NE)" doesn't have any effect - nothing moves north-east? Is this because the towardcamera command is overwriting it?

Comment: Have you tried it with `L=Label("$A$", align=NE)`?